# Mysql select with IF function sub query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a query to work with php. Basically it should first check that a specific booking has not been made then query database for all available vehicles and drivers.

This is the query so far:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM bookings LEFT JOIN status WHERE bookings.status_id = '.$booking.')
            BEGIN
                select * 
                FROM bookings      as b 
                LEFT JOIN drivers  as d where b.driver_id !="d.driver_id"
                LEFT JOIN vehicles as v where b.vehicle_id !="v.vehicle_id"
                LEFT JOIN status   as s where b.status_id !="'.$booking.'"
                ORDER BY b.bookingDate DESC
            END
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: The easiest (and normal) way is to make 2 seperate DB calls

Comment: I need the IF() function to test that there are some bookings, else run the sub query... not at the moment I'm just getting an error, I've tried other ways with google'd tips but no luck. I need it to test for the supplied value from the php var $booking.

Comment: Do you want to check if bookings table has status then execute the sub query ?

Comment: @Loading.. I want to first check if there are bookings where status_id=$booking as supplied via php, if not then run the sub query...

Comment: so you need to check status_id in bookings table only ?

Comment: @Loading.. Yes in the IF() function where condition is status_id = $booking value....

Answer (score 0):

Join bookings:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bookings      as b 
LEFT JOIN drivers  as d where b.driver_id !="d.driver_id"
LEFT JOIN vehicles as v where b.vehicle_id !="v.vehicle_id"
LEFT JOIN status   as s where b.status_id !="'.$booking.'"
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM bookings 
    WHERE bookings.status_id = '.$booking.'
    LIMIT 1
) t
ORDER BY b.bookingDate DESC
```